# Crashes on DateFormatter.localizedString

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsdateformatter, nslocalizedstring

App crashes on converting date&time to current locale. Wondering would be the possible scenario of crash. Below is the code for formatting for the current locale.

```
let date =  DateFormatter.localizedString(from: logMessage.timestamp, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .short)
```

Crash Report:

```
0  libicucore.A.dylib             0x181b59250 icu::Calendar::adoptTimeZone(icu::TimeZone*) + 24
1  CoreFoundation                 0x181e0ede4 __cficu_ucal_setTimeZone + 64
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181e0ede4 __cficu_ucal_setTimeZone + 64
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181d98dc4 __ResetUDateFormat + 1668
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181d984ec __SetUpCFDateFormatter + 344
5  Foundation                     0x1827915b0 -[NSDateFormatter _regenerateFormatter] + 280
6  Foundation                     0x182791314 -[NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:] + 152
7  Foundation                     0x182790efc +[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:] + 124
```

logMessage.timestamp is a Date object

Comment: What is logMessage.timestamp? It should be a valid `Date` object. Actually this shouldn't even compile otherwise o.O

Comment: What is your timezone, calendar, locale?

Comment: Do you call that function concurrently from different threads?

Comment: To debug this, set a breakpoint on the line in question. When you hit that breakpoint, examine the value of `logMessage.timestamp`. If it's nil, or contains something other than a Date object, that's the cause of your problem. Also note what thread you are in. If you aren't in the main thread, that's your cause.

Comment: logMessage.timestamp is a Date object

Comment: @MartinR   calling that function multiple times

Comment: Could you try this `let date =  autoreleasepool {return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .short)}`

Comment: @DuncanC: Actually – according to the documentation – DateFormatter is thread-safe since iOS 7.

Comment: @MartinR Timezone is "Asia/Kolkata", locale - "en_US", calendar - Gregorian

Comment: Have you found a solution for this crash? @VJVJ